# Show that $HB^2 + HC^2 + 5DM^2 = 2DB^2 + 2DC^2$ as follows.

Tags: geometry

**Edit**

Let $ABC$ be triangle with the orthocenter $H$, the circumcenter $O$, and $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Let $D$ lies on $BC$ such that $AD \perp BC$. Let $\omega$ be the circle with diameter $OH$. If $BC$ is tangent to
$\omega$, then show that
\begin{equation*}
HB^2 + HC^2 + 5DM^2 = 2DB^2 + 2DC^2.
\end{equation*}

I have tried, but get stuck and always back to the start because only using the Pythagorean theorem and not using the given circle $\omega$. How to show it?

Comment: i'm using geogebra and it works fine. but, the problem is the proof

Comment: Some picture please....

Comment: For those who wants a picture, I created one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rufyf.png

Comment: I see you are quite an ignorant. You can't put a picture, you don't show any effort and you can't say even thank you for trying help you!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Let the centre of the circle with diameter $OH$ be $P$ and let its point of tangency with $BC$ be $K$. Extend $AD$ to meet the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $L$. Draw $HK$,  $KO$, $PK$, $HB$, $HC$ & $BL$. $PK\perp BC$ & $HP=PK=PO$.

Since the parallel lines $HD$, $PK$ and $OM$ divide the transversal $HPO$ into two equal segments $HP$ and $PO$, they must divide $DKM$ in a similar way.
$\Rightarrow   DK=KM=\frac{DM}{2}$

The circle with diameter $OH$ touches $BC$ at $K$; Hence $\triangle HKO$ is right angled at $K$.

Observe that, $\triangle HDK\sim \triangle KMO$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{HD}{DK}=\frac{KM}{OM}$        $\Rightarrow   \left(\frac{DM}{2}\right)^2 = HD\cdot OM$

$DM=\frac{BC}{2}-BD=DC-\frac{BC}{2}$    $\Rightarrow  DM=\frac{\left(\frac{BC}{2}-BD\right)+\left(DC-\frac{BC}{2}\right)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(DC-BD\right)$

Since $\angle HBD=90-\angle C=\angle DAC=\angle LAC=\angle LBC=\angle LBD$ and $BD\perp HL$, $HD=DL$.

$\Rightarrow AD\cdot HD=AD\cdot DL=BD\cdot DC$

Hence, $HB^2+HC^2+5DM^2$

$=\left(HD^2+BD^2\right)+(HD^2+DC^2)+20HD\cdot OM$

$=\left(BD^2+DC^2\right)+2HD^2+20HD\cdot OM$

$2HD^2+20(HD\cdot OM)$

$=2HD\left(HD+10OM\right)$

$=2HD\left(HD+2OM+8OM\right)$

Since, $O$,$G$ & $H$ lie on the Euler line and $\frac{AG}{GM}=2$, $AH=2OM$.

Thus, $2HD\left(HD+AH+8OM\right)$

$=2HD\left(AD+8OM\right)$

$=2HD\cdot AD+16HD\cdot OM$

$=2BD\cdot DC+\left(2DM\right)^2$

$=2BD\cdot DC+\left(DC-BD\right)^2 =BD^2+DC^2$

Therefore, $HB^2+HC^2+5DM^2$

$=(BD^2+DC^2)+2HD^2+20HD\cdot OM=\boxed {2(BD^2+DC^2)}$.

Comment: Because $H$ is reflected onto circumcircle in $BC$, $HD⋅AD = BD⋅DC$! Very nice. That's where I was stuck. +1

Comment: what is $G$ ???

Comment: $G$ is the centroid of $ABC$ ???

Comment: G is the centroid of triangle ABC. I had avoided drawing it as i was assuming everyone to be familiar with the Euler line and its properties.